# How to get PHP manual references automatically in PHPStorm 8?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm a newbie and there is so much to learn. I would like to see PHP Manual reference if I type a function. Something like this:

```
    strlen()

    int strlen ( string $string )
    Returns the length of the given string.

    example:
    <?php
    $str = 'abcdef';
    echo strlen($str); // 6

    $str = ' ab cd ';
    echo strlen($str); // 7
    ?>
```

That would be nice to see somewhere in the IDE. "Show quick doc on mouse move" in version 8 is not available anymore under Edit menu. Ideally I would like to set phpStorm so that I can 
1) see a pinned window somewhere that 
2) updates automatically as I type new functions with appropriate 
3) PHP Documentation reference

Comment: Does [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/07/autopopup-documentation-feature/) not work anymore? I don't have current access to my workstation.

Comment: *""Show quick doc on mouse move" in version 8 is not available anymore under Edit menu."* What? It never was there in first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible (different) ways:

1. Enable `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Show quick documentation on mouse move`

   [image]
2. `View | Quick Documentation` -- you can **pin it** (so it's stays permanently on a screen) and enable auto-updating of docs for element under caret (*available once it became pinned*; a button next to "X" called `Auto-update from source`).

   [image]

Comment: Errr... For some reason all I see is "function call" and "source" file name on whatever function I mouse over. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2sGR97D.png

Comment: Just checked (PhpStorm v8.0.3 on Windows 7) -- works fine (tried all 3 methods: each individually and both combined). Right now I may only suggest to try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.